# Blank page when calling JSP file via url pattern

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Using Netbeans I'm setting up a MVC-powered website on localhost. I've set up the controller as a servlet which points client requests to the relevant JSP pages.

When I try to access the JSP files directly I have no problems, but when I try via the url patterns set in the controller servlet I get blank pages. I know the pointing is working because if I request a url pattern that hasn't been named in the controller servlet I get a 404 not found error.

Here is the code for the servlet template file:

```
 public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userPath = request.getServletPath();
    if (userPath.equals("/book")) {   
    }
    String url = "/WEB-INF" + userPath + ".jsp";
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userPath = request.getServletPath();
    if (userPath.equals("/profile")) {
    } else if (userPath.equals("/updates")) {
    } else if (userPath.equals("/mybooks")) {
    }
    String url = "/WEB-INF/view" + userPath + ".jsp";
    request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}

 }
```

The ControllerServlet file contains an additional line on top of the standard HTTPServlet code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ControllerServlet", loadOnStartup = 1, urlPatterns = {"/profile", "/mybooks", "/updates", "/book"})
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>The relative path to images of book covers.</description>
    <param-name>coversImagePath</param-name>
    <param-value>img/bookCovers</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <description>header and footer settings</description>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/book.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
        <include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
<resource-ref>
    <description>Connects to database for bookshelves application.</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/bookshelves</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "access the JSP pages directly? If they're under the WEB-INF directory you can't. Are they under a WEB-INF/view/ directory?

Comment: By "access the JSP pages directly" I meant this:     http://localhost:8080/bookshelves/book.jsp As you'll see from the code one of the pages is NOT located within WEB-INF (book.jsp) and yet when I request this as http://localhost:8080/bookshelves/book I still cannot access it. I altered the path in the servlet template code to String url = userPath + ".jsp"; and I still get a blank page.

Comment: As I see from the code, all JSP IS assumed to be under `WEB-INF`, because `url` always includes `WEB-INF`. Not sure what the code/directory layout really is; please edit the code and include the exact directory layout.

Comment: Right Dave, I've updated the code. Can you take another look? I'm still getting a blank page.

Comment: What's the layout under `WEB-INF`?

Comment: *Please* remove the comments and blank lines that don't add value: they're not relevant to the question, and force unnecessary scrolling.

Comment: Look here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/718/fypdirlayout.jpg/

Comment: Right, I've removed comments and blank lines as requested.

Comment: A Struts config file? As Balus suggested, please include further details, like your web.xml etc. to see if something else is interfering.

Comment: Should I not have a struts file? I've included web.xml above.

Comment: Not if you're not using Struts. Are you also using JSF? I think just *.jsp would be enough in the jsp-config section, depending on what you're actually doing.

Comment: I'm using JSF to include the header and footer dynamically in my pages. I tried deleting the struts file and the project wouldn't build.

Comment: JSF is overkill for including headers; there's `<jsp:include>` (among others). You can't arbitrarily remove a single configuration file--if you're not using Struts, you shouldn't have *any* Struts libraries, configs, etc. Are you using it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder. It'll fix 2 things:

1. You won't get a blank page.
2. You won't be able to access the JSP directly (which is correct and desired behaviour!)

You need to fix 2 other problems not directly related to the concrete problem:

1. Never suppress exceptions unless you know what you're doing. Remove that `try-catch`.
2. Never ignore server logs. The `forward()` did throw an exception.

Additional benefit is that you won't get a blank page anymore and thus will see your mistake immediately in flavor of a self-explaining exception (only if you didn't override the server default HTTP 500 error page by some custom `<error-page>` which in turn doesn't show anything of the exception).

Comment: Right, I moved all JSPs into the WEB-INF dir and I'm still getting a blank page. However, I am now unable to access the JSP directly, which as you say is desired. I removed the try-catch block and still I get a blank page.

Comment: Then there's more into the code which you left from the question. Maybe you've another bogus filter or servlet in the request-response chain? Please post information that sufficiently so that it still reproduces the concrete problem on a new and completely blank project.

Comment: I created a new project from scratch and all appears to be working correctly. Somewhere along the way during the creation of the original project I must have altered some settings. I'm not sure which but either way the ControllerServlet is now acting as desired. Thanks to both of you for your help!

Comment: Your `web.xml` is by the way suspicous. You're mixing 2 completely different MVC frameworks in one webapp. Struts is a rather legacy action based MVC framework and JSF2 is a modern component based MVC framework. But you're creating a custom servlet to act as controller instead of utilizing either of those MVC frameworks. Also the JSPF files and the JNDI resource pointing to bookshelf demo webapp suggests that you're reading heavily outdated JSP/Servlet tutorials. Do you know what you're doing?