# How to display JSP files in browser correctly?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm following the [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20220810213921/https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/spring-security-role-based-access-authorization-example) where there are `JSP` files and I'm struggling with displaying them correctly in browser.

In my project I have `LoginController` class as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/page")
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/welcomePage")
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("welcomePage");
        return model;
    }

    /*
     * Updated homePage.jsp file to provide User and Admin Roles specific activities.
     * homePage.jsp
     */
    @GetMapping("/homePage")
    public ModelAndView homePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("homePage");
        return model;
    }

    /*
     * '/userPage' is used by USER Role to access and perform Normal user activities.
     */
    @GetMapping("/userPage")
    public ModelAndView userPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("userPage");
        return model;
    }

    /*
     * '/adminPage' is used by ADMIN Role to access and perform Admin user activities.
     * ADMIN role can access “/userPage” URL too.
     */
    @GetMapping("/adminPage")
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("adminPage");
        return model;
    }

    @GetMapping("/loginPage")
    public ModelAndView loginPage(@RequestParam(value = "error",required = false) String error,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "logout",   required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid Credentials provided.");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addObject("message", "Logged out from successfully.");
        }

        model.setViewName("loginPage");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Also I have some `JSP` files which are locating inside `/WEB-INF/view` as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49513293/8370915) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8640713/8370915) answer:

*adminPage.jsp*:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="https://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<h3>Admin Page</h3>

<c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
<form id="logout" action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logout').submit()">Logout</a>
</c:if>
```

*homePage.jsp*

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="https://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/userPage">User</a> | <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/adminPage">Admin</a> | <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logout').submit()">Logout</a>

<h3>Welcome to Rest API Application</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Java 8 tutorial</li>
    <li>Spring tutorial</li>
    <li>Gradle tutorial</li>
    <li>BigData tutorial</li>
</ul>

<c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
<form id="logout" action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

*loginPage.jsp*

```
<%@ include file="welcomePage.html" %>
<hr/>

<h3>Login Form</h3>
<%
    String profile_msg = (String) request.getAttribute("profile_msg");
    if (profile_msg != null) {
        out.print(profile_msg);
    }
    String login_msg = (String) request.getAttribute("login_msg");
    if (login_msg != null) {
        out.print(login_msg);
    }
%>
<br/>
<form action="loginPage.jsp" method="post">
    Email:<input type="text" name="email"/><br/><br/>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>"
</form>
```

*userPage.jsp*

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="https://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<h3>User Page</h3>

<c:url value="/logout" var="logoutUrl" />
<form id="logout" action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logout').submit()">Logout</a>
</c:if>
```

In my application I have `application.properties` with configurations as:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/webapp/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

But I'm getting always the error as:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 19 20:54:05 CET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

My `POM` file contains:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can someone tell, please, am I missing something and what do I need to add to display them in my browser correctly? Can it be the confusing with [Spring Security configuration](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/fe9ec2811a897dbf606538a9d6f0035d#file-loginsecurityconfig-java-L49)?

My current [logs](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/4201320dc7e862cdcb5ce7d6b20971b1).

I can provide more information if it helps to detect the cause of issue.

Thank you in advance for any smart ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *workaround* is:

after I put all `JSP` files instead of `/webapp/WEB-INF/view/` directory to `/resources/templates/jsp/`.

And added inside `application.properties` instead:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

another classpath:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/jsp/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
```

it started work for me.

Also be aware if you have all important dependencies inside `POM` as:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```